# How to run the function between some iloc

Tags: pandas

how to run function the the data frame between some rows iloc

Can i do like below?

```
df(['out'].iloc[100::]) = df(['in'].iloc[[100::]).apply(func)
```

The above will apply the function after 100 to till last row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) then get positions of columns names by [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html):

```
df.iloc[100:, df.columns.get_loc('out')] = df.iloc[100:, df.columns.get_loc('in')].apply(func)
```

Or use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for select by labels, then use indexing of index values:

```
df.loc[df.index[100:], 'out'] = df.loc[df.index[100:], 'in'].apply(func)
```

Comment: first one is working fine, second one throws value error? why, can you explain

Comment: @ain - Maybe problem is second should be `loc`, not `iloc`